# HTML generated by Dreamweaver

Tags: html, xhtml

When i run the following code below it works in dreamweaver but when i go to view it in a web broswer nothin shows.

The code is

```
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
  <td align="center">

    <form action="search.php" method="get">

<table><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="query" id="query" size="40" value="<?  print quote_replace($query);?>" action="include/js_suggest/suggest.php" columns="2" autocomplete="off" delay="1500">    
</div> 
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Search!">
</td></tr></table>
```

When i go to view the source code in chrome it only loads

```
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">

<tr>

  <td align="center">



    <form action="search.php" method="get">



<table><tr><td>
```

Comment: i think you have an error in your post. is the part of `action="include...` in the form tag or outside?

Comment: Orphan? closing DIV in a table cell also

Comment: I'm going to guess it's throwing an error on this line of code: `<?  print quote_replace($query);?>`.  Try using `<?php ?>` tags instead of the shorthand.

Comment: Your php short tags are inaccurate as well.. make sure to change to `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: @thedaian .. I lost the duel.

Comment: Thank you @Michael @dave_kiss @Alex_K thank guys your 3 tips helped solve this issue, Thanks alot :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer as the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your host to see if they've enabled the `<?` tag. It's not turned on by default. If it's not, it's probably causing Chrome a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your syntax. What you've pasted isn't valid. It looks like your'e closing your form twice, or you have an extra set of quotes in the "get" area.

On a side note, I suggest removing display related HTML attributes in favor of CSS. It will help keep a clear distinction between function and look.